# Why omit the auxiliary verb here?

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé, voix-passive

I know that the auxiliary verb can be omitted in sentences when you're repeating verbs in a clause that have the same tense/mood.
But this omission is at the beginning of the sentence, and is definitely talking about the past, so I was wondering why the auxiliary is omitted?:

> Fabienne Kabou est condamnée... À ce titre, le verdict rendu le 24 juin par les jurés est incertain.

The source is journalistic, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

"Rendu" is a past participle used as an adjective (attributive, or in French, "*épithète*"). The use of an auxiliary in the context of the noun phrase "le verdict rendu le 24 juin par les jurés" would make no sense. What would make sense would be replacing the adjectival modifier "rendu  rendu le 24 juin par les jurés" by a relative clause (restrictive).

- À ce titre, le verdict **qui a été** rendu le 24 juin par les jurés est incertain.

Tthat is the only way to introduce auxiliaries in the noun phrase. Journalistic style is not at all in question, and both forms are equally good;  which construction is used is a matter of personal choice.

[Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-30829.php)